# Uniform Distribution Modulo 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-distribution

Let

$x_1 = \sqrt2$ mod $1$

$x_2 = 2x_1$ mod $1$

$x_3 = 2x_2$ mod $1$

continue the process

How to prove the sequence {$x_n$} is uniformly distributed modulo 1

my friend tell me that the question can be solved by Calculus

but I still have no idea

Comment: You just asked this very same question an hour ago.

Comment: What does "uniformly distributed modulo 1" mean?

Comment: I did not describe the question clearly one hour ago. I delete 
previous one

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask questions, edit to clarify instead.

Comment: The sequence {$x_n$} ,n=1,...N of real numbers is said to be uniformly distributed modulo 1 if  for every pair a, b of real numbers with 0 < a < b < 1 we have 

$$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {C\left( \left[ a,b\right] ,N\right) } {N}=b-a$$

$C\left( \left[ a,b\right] ,N\right)$ is counting function

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Are you aware of [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl.27s_criterion) for equidistribution?